# Syntax changes to be observed during migration from Oracle 11g to 12c

Tags: oracle11g, database-migration, oracle12c

I have an Oracle database which is Oracle 11g. If I have to migrate it to 12c, what are all the process to be followed? What are the code-level changes that I should be doing during this migration so as to ensure that all the SQL queries and procedures work fine in the new 12c Version? What are the Syntactical changes that comes to 12c which are not in 11g?

Answer (score 2):

[Upgrading to Oracle database 12c](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/upgrading-to-12c) contains a nice walkthrough, as well as links to other documents such as [Database Upgrade Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/UPGRD/toc.htm) which contains the [Deprecated and Desupported Features](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/UPGRD/deprecated.htm#UPGRD60000) section:

> By deprecate, we mean that the feature is no longer being enhanced but
>   is still supported for the full life of the 12.1 release. By
>   desupported, we mean that Oracle will no longer fix bugs related to
>   that feature and may remove the code altogether.

So - have a look.